# The mouth movement of the robot is synchronous with speech

Tags: speech-recognition, raspberry-pi3, robotics

I work on a human robot project and I want to make this robot move his mouth when he speaks
What is the method? Is there a **sound sensor** or a specialized software **algorithm**?
I want all the things related to it .. and what is the algorithm that makes the movement of the lips consistent with the characters
For example a letter **'O'** makes a robot mouth is round
What techniques are used in this algorithm
thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It probably isn't what you are looking for but for a project where we wanted an animated puppet to do what you're talking we used this software to generate a list of phoneme associated to a sound bite (mp3 file):

http://www.annosoft.com/lipsync-sdks

We then linked relevant mouth image to each phoneme and had the rendering engine follow the sound bite with that list.

The result was pretty convincing.

Hope it helps